# "Angularjs Way" of finding by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Here's the gist of what I'm doing

```
<!-- if user liked post -->
  Show "Unlike" button
<!-- else -->
  Show "Like" button
<!-- end -->
```

In Rails, I would do something like this:

```
<% if @like = current_user.likes.find_by_post_id(@post.id) %>
    Unlike
<% else %>
    Like
<% end %>
```

Assuming I already have over 1,000 posts in my db, **what would be the most efficient way of finding whether or not a user has already liked a post?**

What comes to mind:

1. Being that I'm already injecting the current user's id through a service, maybe I could send a request back..? (I have no clue how I'd do this)
2. Send in an array of all the post ids the current user has liked to see if any of those match the post's id

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we to assume that you have already pulled back the data from the server and we are on the client trying to figure out how to conditionally show or hide the like button for each post?

Comment: Hey @AdamThomas. The data is already pulled from the server but I'm open to other ways of doing this. Maybe I can sort it out (sort of like #2) before displaying it client side

Comment: I would probably pass the user-id back to the server as part of the initial query to pull the post(s). This gives the benefit of having all the posts pre-populated with "liked:true" or "liked:false" for the current user-id. Then all we have to do is use an [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) to display all the posts. Inside the ng-repeat you will be using [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) to conditionally show or hide the Like/Unlike buttons based on the "liked:true" or "liked:false" value for each post.

Comment: @AdamThomas mmm.. What Sam said in his answer below seems simple. But you're saying for each post, send a request back to the server to see if that user has liked that post.  Wouldn't it be less work to just load the ids of who liked the post? Something tells me I should go your route

Comment: Here's my suggestion. When loading a page full of posts I would use my method of passing back the id so you can have a "liked" flag for each row and easily determine whether to show/hide the like/unlike buttons. Once the user drills-down into an individual post to display the details I would use Sam's method of having the ids of everyone who liked the post.

Comment: Actually Sam and I might be saying the same thing after re-reading his post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which will tend to be greater: The number of likes a single item will receive, or the number of times a user has liked something?

Probably the latter.

If you're displaying a lot of items at one time, maybe you can pre-fetch which items the current user has liked within the displayed set.